# Ruby on rails - bind a selected value to a select element for update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can not figure out why this is not working, I saw a couple of examples and seems to be right.

I have two clases that are related, consultant and salary (a salary belongs_to a consultant).

The problem I have is, when I want to edit a salary, the consultant that appears on the form is not bind to the select (in the select it just appears the list as if I was creating a new one)

```
<%= f.select :consultant_id, options_for_select(Consultant.active.map{|s|[s.first_name, s.id]}, params[:consultant_id]), {}, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check your route that the `:consultant_id` param is available on this page. Else you may need to change the `params[:consultant_id]` to something like `salary.consultant_id`

Alternatively, you can use the `collection_select` method as such:

```
f.collection_select(:consultant_id, Consultant.active, :id, :first_name, prompt: true, class: 'form-control')
```

Let me know whichever works for you.

Note: It's not best practice referring to domain object within your view.

Comment: Thank you, with your answer I get it the right way 
<%= select_tag "consultant", options_from_collection_for_select(Consultant.all, 'id', 'personal_info', :selected => @salary.consultant_id ) %>